# Cannot use gem 'vault' and 'k8s-ruby' even though its installed

Tags: ruby

GitLab version: v15.7.5

Image: gitlab-toolbox-ce

I wrote a Ruby script that needed to integrate with the Vault server and create K8S resources.
I tried to install the gems with the command below.

`gem install --install-dir /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0 vault k8s-ruby`

The gems are installed at /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0 directory.
But when I run the Ruby script with the command below.

`gitlab-rails runner /app/scripts/main.rb`

This error message occurred.

If I ran as root.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        13: from /srv/gitlab/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
        12: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        11: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        10: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
         9: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
         8: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
         7: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
         6: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
         5: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
         4: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands/runner/runner_command.rb:42:in `perform'
         3: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands/runner/runner_command.rb:42:in `load'
         2: from /app/scripts/main.rb:10:in `<main>'
         1: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
/srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require': cannot load such file -- vault (LoadError)
```

If I ran as git.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        33: from /srv/gitlab/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
        32: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        31: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        30: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        29: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        28: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
        27: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        26: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        25: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        24: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands/runner/runner_command.rb:33:in `perform'
        23: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:14:in `require_application_and_environment!'
        22: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:22:in `require_application!'
        21: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        20: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        19: from /srv/gitlab/config/application.rb:15:in `<main>'
        18: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.15/lib/bundler.rb:187:in `require'
        17: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
        16: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `each'
        15: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `block in require'
        14: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
        13: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        12: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        11: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        10: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/autoprefixer-rails-10.2.5.1/lib/autoprefixer-rails.rb:39:in `<main>'
         9: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/autoprefixer-rails-10.2.5.1/lib/autoprefixer-rails.rb:39:in `require_relative'
         8: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/autoprefixer-rails-10.2.5.1/lib/autoprefixer-rails/processor.rb:4:in `<main>'
         7: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
         6: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
         5: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
         4: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
         3: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
         2: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/execjs-2.8.1/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<main>'
         1: from /srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/execjs-2.8.1/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
/srv/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/execjs-2.8.1/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:58:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
```

Could someone help me to solve this issue, please? I appreciate it.
Best regards.

I just tried to install the gem as many ways and at many directory. But it is still occurred this issue.